# Rails 3: Get helper_url from path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get the helper_url from the current path. For example if I have the following route:

`get "user/:user_id" => 'user#user_info', :as => 'user_information'`

If I visit `user/31221`, is there any way for me to get the helper_url `user_information` or the string "user/:user_id" (not "user/31221") from the url?

I can get the controller and the action with `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.env['PATH_INFO'])`, but I am not able to get the rest of this information. I can do it with rake routes but I want to do this for a very specific logging purpose.

Comment: What is your aim? How you will use that helper method? Maybe there is better way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information from:

```
Rails.application.routes.router.recognize(request) do |route, matches, parameters| 
 # Get the path name in here
end
```

Comment: I'm sorry I think I may have been unclear. I literally mean I would want to take the url and get out a either `user_information_path` or `user/:user_id`. I could do this with request.fullpath, but then I would have to parse the params on a per route basis.

Comment: Updated with a way to get path name